# jQuery Mobile - Can't access $.mobile.loading() method?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to use jqm's loading spinner as details here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/loader.html

Calling `$.mobile.loading('show');` or any other `$.mobile.loading(...)` methods from within my jqm app or from firebug console does not work.

**The error message in the console is:** `$.mobile.loading is not a function`

---

If i open firebug and run `console.log($.mobile);` i get the below object with no `loading` or `loader` methods.

[image]

I have also tried including the below code, but with no joy:

```
$( document ).bind( 'mobileinit', function(){
  $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.text = "loading";
  $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible = false;
  $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.theme = "a";
  $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.html = "";
});
```

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Which jquery mobile version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you are not using the last version of jQuery Mobile, and the loading method is quite new (don't know which version was released in). Try using

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()
```

Comment: Yes, I believe the $.mobile.loading() method is only available as of version 1.2, which is still in beta.

Comment: @RodrigoDias from docs: `Deprecated in 1.2 - use $.mobile.loading( 'show' ) instead, see examples above`. The question is about v1.1

Answer (score 1):

1. $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); for show
2. $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); for hide
3. $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("a","Loading please wait..."); for show
   with theme and message